# Ajax Post with the same value from variable

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am using the following code to submit a form with ajax /php.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="saqhiddenid" class="saqhiddenid" type="hidden" value="' . $pci_saq_id . '" />
    <button type="button" name="editsaq" class="editsaq">Edit</button>
</form>

$(function () {

        $(".editsaq").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            saqhiddenid: $('input[name="saqhiddenid"]').val()
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {

            some code

        }
    });

}); 

});
```

The submit works as it should.
I can see in the HTML code that the values of " saqhiddenid " are different, but when i am submitting the form, i always get the results from the highest value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. We will be able to help if you can explain the problem clearly.

Comment: the problem is that despite the value of saqhiddenid that i am posting is different in each form, the value actually posted is always the same, the 1st one to be precise.

Comment: Do you have multiple forms on same page with `input` named `saqhiddenid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you don't disable the actual form submit. so you make your ajax call, but the form also gets submitted with the old value. You need:

```
$(".editsaq").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this).closest('form');
   var value = form.find('input[name="saqhiddenid"]').val();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        saqhiddenid: value
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {

        some code

    }
};
```

Comment: had already tried that, not working, still getting the resutls from posting the same value

Comment: How are the submit values different, if you are sending the value you got from the input field? Also what is 'highest value' ?

Comment: there are multiple forms in the page where the value is determined by the variable $pci_saq_id

Comment: Ah I se, your problem is it was getting the value form the first element it matched. What you need is to get the value from the current form. Edited my answer, take a look

Comment: thnx , it works, gives more flexibility since you are searching for the specific variable.

Answer (score 1):

In case of multiple forms with same input name, it will always pick the first input value.

If your `form` structure is same as posted try below code:

```
data: {
        saqhiddenid: $(this).prev().val()
    }
```

Comment: it's working! thank you very much Samir. i figured that it could be something like that, but couldnt find the right syntax. thnx again!

Comment: My answer is addresses thi sbetter since it actually searches for the form element. For prev() to work the elements HAVE to be exactly next to each other. So if you use this approch and the html changes even slightly it will break